# Java Rest API Calling another Rest without waiting for the response - in JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jax-rs

I have a case to be implemented in my project.Below is a sample rest service which has to be implemented

```
    @GET
    @Path("/test/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getData(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        //Some processing to get value of String
        String result = doSomeProcessing();

        //I want to return this result to GUI and call one more rest api  
        // and end this process without waiting for response from second 
        //call

       new Thread(){
       //call second rest api
       }.start();

       return result;      

    }
```

Is this good approach using new Thread to call second rest API and return result without waiting for response from second rest API ?
I have also looked into Asynchronous Rest call, but it doesn't exactly suit my requirement. Please advice. Thanks in Advance

Comment: So the client doesn't need the result of the second API call?

Comment: Yes, client dosen't need the result of second API call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid starting [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)s directly. Consider an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead as shown below:

```java
@Singleton
@Path("foo")
public class FooResource {

    private ExecutorService executor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onCreate() {

        // Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number 
        // of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue
        this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool​(10);
    }

    @GET
    public Response getFoo() {

        String result = doSomeProcessing();

        // Submits a Runnable task for execution
        executor.submit(new LongRunningTask());

        return Response.ok(result).build();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void onDestroy() {

        // Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted 
        // tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.
        this.executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

```java
public class LongRunningTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            // Simulate a long running task
            // Don't do it in a real application
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Explore the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) API for details on how to create an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instance.

---

In Java SE and in a Servlet container, you can use an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for your long running task. In a Java EE container, you should use a [`ManagedExecutorService`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) instead:

```java
@Resource
ManagedExecutorService executor;
```

Once it's a resource managed by the container, you don't need to instantiate and dispose it manually.

Answer (score 3):

I not sure what do you exactly mean by "calling the second REST API" so I  assume that you're sending an HTTP request to another external API, i.e "second REST API".

You can use [Apache HC](http://hc.apache.org) to send the request and skip waiting for the response. See its [fluent API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/index.html) which is easy to use. [Async.execute](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Async.html) is the one that ought to be used in your case. The `Async` class uses a thread-pool underneath to handle background requests.

I should mention that I haven't used any other HTTP client libraries. There might be other choices out there with almost the same functionality.

**Side Note** I strongly suggest `ExecutorService`, esp. `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of creating new threads. It has more control over life-cycle of threads and manages system resource efficiently. `ExecutorService` has methods for fire and forget scenarios (`submit`). However, this only makes sense when your "second REST API" call is actually implemented in another method in your application and lives within the same JRE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say yes and no; there is nothing "wrong" about calling another service asynchronously (ex: a metrics subsystem to register that a call to that service was made). However, I wouldn't create threads straight in the `getData` method, I would use another (injected) object to hide the implementation detail (ex: just calling some sort of `myOtherService.submit(something)`. That way you can easily switch from something synchronous, to asnychronous and even change the async method to your liking.

As to the actual implementation, instead of creating threads, I would submit callables to an executor service instead so you save the overhead of creating actual system threads, or you could even have one or more threads waiting on a blocking queue and just put jobs in that queue for threads to pick them up.